# From logged footage to clips

Tags: premiere, editing

I've got 40 hours of logged footage. I created a new project for each tape, captured the tape, logged it with pen and paper, wrote in some metadata for the file. Now I need to go back through and create clips from the good bits in the footage. How should I do this? Should I make  another new project, import all the avi files into it and mark clips from those (I don't know how to do this), creating new clips in the project library which I can then drag into the timeline and arrange? I've experimented a bit with this process but I'm not too sure.

Comment: any reason you created a new project for each tape, Normally when you log and capture a tape you will do this within a single project and have each tape as a video file.

Comment: yeah, there is no reason. I should import all the files into one project then?

Comment: yea, one project with folders and within the folders the timelines, video files, sound files etc, I would make a folder for each with appropriate names of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More recently I had moved to individual clip logging at the logging level and doing batch captures that would capture the individual clips.  With direct to disk systems, it also uses distinct files, so it's been a while since I did this.

That said, what I did for going through long sets of bulk captured footage back in the day was to place the clips on V2 or V3 in my timeline approximately around where I expected to use them.  If I thought they were interesting but didn't know where they would be, I'd put them in another sequence as a set of B-roll shots to pull from.

I then arranged them in to a rough cut, pulling in clips from my B-roll shots where needed.  This works best if you have a pretty decent familiarity with all your footage and a decent idea of your end result, but can also work (I'll be it kind of painfully) if you have less of an idea.  It just takes more culling passes to get it worked down and more video tracks to place clips on.

I also always shifted everything down as I built the rough cut and removed clips I wasn't going to use once I determined they weren't needed.